# Max Heapify algorithm results

Tags: java, algorithm

I've been playing around with some of the Algorithms in the Intro to Algorithms textbook, in specific I'm trying get a Binary Heap to work 100% correctly. I have a curious feeling that the example that I'm working with isn't correct, and I was wondering if anyone can help point me in the right direction.

Given the array

```
int[ ] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 14, 16 };
```

The result I get from MaxHeapify is

```
[ 16, 14, 9, 10, 7, 8, 3, 1, 4, 2 ]
```

However, after doing a few Google searches, I found that people who use this exact array as an example expect the result to be:

```
[ 16, 14, 10, 8, 7, 9, 3, 2, 4, 1 ]
```

What confuses me is that the result that my MaxHeapify method gives satisfies the Heap property, but it's different than what is expected. Below is my implementation in Java

```
public static void BuildMaxHeap( int[ ] arr )
{
    for( int i = (int)Math.floor( arr.length - 1 ); i >= 0; i-- )
        MaxHeapify( arr, i );
}
public static void MaxHeapify( int[ ] arr, int i )
{
    int left = 2 * i + 1;
    int right = 2 * i + 2;
    int largest = i;

    if( left < arr.length && arr[ left ] > arr[ largest ] )
        largest = left;
    if( right < arr.length && arr[ right ] > arr[ largest ] )
        largest = right;
    if( largest != i )
    {
        int temp = arr[ i ];
        arr[ i ] = arr[ largest ];
        arr[ largest ] = temp;
        MaxHeapify( arr, largest );
    }
}
```

Comment: Both of those are valid heaps. You just seem to be doing your max-heapify slightly differently.

Comment: Why are you `floor`ing `length`? This is a nop.

Comment: Jpm, there is a proof in the textbook that says every element in the sub-array from `A[ ( floor( n/2 ) + 1 ) ...  n ]` is already a leaf, and therefore each is a 1-element heap.

Comment: I think you mean `(int)Math.floor(arr.length / 2)`, then. Except that the `floor` is still unnecessary, since integer division truncates.

Comment: Yes! You're completely correct! I had just switched that `arr.length - 1` to try something different but forgot that when I re-added the floor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The heaps that you've shown are both valid. There's nothing to worry about.

There are multiple ways to order subnodes.

Consider the simplest case of swapping left with right:

```
   14         14
 10  9   vs  9  10
...  ...   ...  ...
```

Comment: Thus, a good test assertion would test that the result verifies the heap property rather that checking the order of values in the array used to implement the heap...

Comment: @Snicolas Precisely. Red-black trees are typically tested for the preservation of their properties as well.

Answer (score 2):

Your heaps are valid. They are different because the array is not necessarily sorted when you apply neither of these methods. That's what Heapsort is for. Just one detail, in your BuildMaxHeap you may want to change

```
for( int i = (int)Math.floor( arr.length - 1 ); i >= 0; i-- )
```

to

```
for( int i = arr.length / 2; i >= 0; i-- )
```

The reason I say this is because you can start from the last node that has leaves as it's children, since leaves are always a max_heap.